# How to convert a unit datatype to a string in SML

Tags: string, printing, type-conversion, sml

Basically I want to print something in the unit data type via my own structure and signature that requires this to happen as its data type is unit and i want to "show" it.

So I need to "print" it.

I tried the `unit.to String` function, and tried to convert it to a character first, but to no avail.

```
print(unit.to String(symex))
```

-undefined variable or constructor unit.to String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unit` type has only one value, `()`. That is, the value doesn't contain any information.

Creating a `unit` to `string` function is rather simple:

```
fun unitToString () = "()"
```

As there is only one possible value, it can have only one possible representation as a string.

However, since the value doesn't actually contain any information, you most likely don't want to operate on the `unit` value, but rather some other value.